# Django view does not redirect to details page

Tags: python, django, django-views, redirect, django-urls

I've created a form and view in Django. I can see the add new post form when I go to http://localhost:8000/post/new/ but after I complete all required fields and click submit the page just refreshes itself and I am not redirected to the post details page.

Here's my views.py

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.createdAt = timezone.now()
            post.writer = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('posts:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,"posts/post_new.html",context)
```

Here's my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name="post_list"),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<post_title_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="col">
<form method='POST' class='post_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}" name= "{{ form.title.html_name }}" placeholder="Enter post title">
      {{ form.title.errors }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.comment.id_for_label }}">Description here:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="{{ form.comment.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.comment.html_name }}" aria-describedby="descriptionHelpBlock"></textarea>
    <small id="descriptionHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
      Describe your post in this text box. 
    </small>
    {{ form.comment.errors }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.image.id_for_label }}">Upload picture here</label>
    <input type="file" id="{{ form.image.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.image.html_name }}" class="form-control-file">
    {{ form.image.errors }}
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your post getting created without problems?

Comment: unfortunately the post doesn't get created in the db either

Comment: If post is not created - it looks like form is not valid. I suggest to print `form.errors` completely to see what's wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your url is expecting a slug value as argument. You need to pass the title slug of the post in **redirect** instead of pk.
Try:

```
 return redirect('posts:post_detail', post_title_slug=post.slug)
```

I assumed your slug field as post.slug

Comment: I've changed the redirect to this and still same result

Comment: Seems your form is invalid. Try adding **{{ form.errors }}** anywhere inside your template and try submitting your form again.